# Node.js - process millions of http post items without blocking

Tags: node.js

Using node.js, what is the best way to process a million items in an HTTP post request without blocking the server? My only guess is some sort of message queue, but I really have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use a lib like async.js to create non-blocking loops.
https://github.com/caolan/async

```
var async = require("async");

async.each(yourArrayOfThings, function(oneItem, callback) {
    // do something
    // ...
    return callback(null);
}, function(err) {
    // if any of the callbacks returned an error, err would equal that error
});
```

Give some more information on what your processing needs are, if this is not an applicable solution for you.

Comment: at some point, would it be a good idea just to fork another process to take care of the request and then have the process notify the event loop when it's done?

Comment: actually node does this under the hood for synchronous operations, it piles them up in a queue with a threadpool. so this would be the way to go if you have a block of code that you cannot run in an asynchronous fashion and still want to maintain the http code nonblocking.